# Jira rest jql, get all open issues for user x on project y

Tags: jira-rest-api, jql

I looked in other answers, but could not find it.

I want to output a list of the tasks I am assigned to.

I looked in the JIRA API reference and found this

> https://optibus.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?ql=project%20%3D%20%22OS%22%20AND%20assignee%20%3D%20currentUser()%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC'

it doesn't filter, it just shows me all 10000 tasks in the system.

How can I get only the open tasks that are open for a certain user, I am looking for time, task title, task id)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the exact GET call or URL, the error is the query parameter for JQL. You used `ql` instead of `jql` and that's why it's returning the unexpected result set.

Comment: how can I ask for specific fields? i want summary (only) for all tasks and subtasks.

Comment: If you only need specific fields, use the query parameter `fields` and supply the field you need. In your case, `field=summary`